# SpriteKit - didMovetoView is not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

This is my code for the view controller

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}
```

And this is my code for the GameScene

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {
       override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
            print("gets called")
        }
```

But for some reasons, in the debug area, it didn't print "gets called", which indicates that didMove didn't even get called. What's happening here? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Is the scene being displayed? Xcode has a very capable debugger, you could set a break point on `if let view = self.view as! SKView?` and see if the scene is being presented.

Comment: For this to work, the .sks file needs to have the custom class field of the scene set to "GameScene".  The first thing I would do is double-check that you have done so in the .sks editor.  If that's the case, then it might be that you have module name issues.  If you've got a project with multiple targets, this can happen - you may have to enter the module name from your build settings to get it to work for that particular target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I finally sort that out.**

My project name contains a period at the end. Like the name "XXXX.". After several experimentations, I discovered that I can simply solve the problem by removing the period.

Answer (score 8):

The iOS 9 way

In your GameViewController try to directly present your GameScene instead of a generic SKScene.

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") { 
...
```

Remember "fileNamed" is not the name of the .swift file, its the name of the .sks file which is used for the xCode level editor.

The new iOS 10 way

It seems Apple now prefers to pass a generic SKScene like you are trying.

```
  if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") { ... }
```

To make it work go to the relevant .sks file and go to the inspector on the right. Click the second last item (custom class) and enter the name of the .swift file into the custom class field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Xcode 8's default SpriteKit project uses SKScene not GameScene in this context. There is a "Custom Class" field in the .sks file that specifies the SKScene subclass. In the default, the custom class is set to GameScene. Perhaps, the OP unintentionally changed this.

Comment: This is not the best approach. It is preferred to use `SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")` because this can be made dynamic to cater for an approach that initialises to a current scene e.g. `SKScene(fileNamed: currentScene)` where `currentScene` could be persisted to e.g. `NSUserDefaults` so the player can be returned to a particular scene when they restart the game.

Comment: This is only true if using iOS 8 due to a bug,  for iOS 9 and later,  should be using Mark Brownswords approach

Answer (score 2):

This could happen because you don't have the related `SKS` (`GameScene.sks` in your case) file reference to your project, check if you have added it or removed/renamed due to mistake.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

use

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
```

instead of

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView)
```

Maybe a naming inconsistency in the documentation/API...

Comment: This is simply a difference between Swift 2 and 3... Using the Swift 2 version in Swift 3 will give an error saying to change it to Swift 3 version

Answer (score -1):

I second what Tom Xue said as someone who spent way too long looking for the answer to this.  I had a hyphen in my app name and that seems to have been causing the problem.  When I renamed my project, the scene was presented as it should have been.

Comment: Your post is not a technical solution. That kind of thing is what the comments section below questions and answers are for. Very frowned upon to use the Answer section to have conversation and ask question, it is for explicit focused solutions to technical problems only.

Comment: Interesting assessment of my post.  Would it have been perceived differently if I'd not mentioned the other person who had a similar solution, with whom I was not trying to have a conversation?  As in, if it'd simply been something like, "SpriteKit seems not to like punctuation in app/project names.  Have had similar issues with presenting GameScene that've been resolved by changing the project's name."?

Comment: Noobs here don't generally understand the site, its rules, the community, how things work here and why they're handled that way. I'm just telling you the site guidelines are *very* clear about what constitutes a question and answer. Look at the review link at the top, where the community moderates the forum and browse the topics or even contribute. I've been here a long time. I have learned these things. Your post came up in a review cue for a first post for a new user or something like that, and I was just following the moderation guidelines. I didn't vote to close your post, only to inform.

Comment: BTW: Do you see the little "1" next to my reply to your post? That's because someone else in the review queue saw my comment and agreed with the assessment. I'm not trying to bust your chops, or be petty or mean. But once you've seen thousands of questions and answers you understand more the reason answers are supposed to be self-contained *technical* **solutions** only.

Comment: Finally, don't just take my word for it, please read the guidelines: [How to post a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)